# Image on Side of Screen Linking

Tags: css, hyperlink

I have an image floating on the left side of the screen. Link can be seen here (www.mibsolutionsllc.com/proc_dev). How can I make that image a link? What is the terminology so I can research it on Google for answer? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I am misunderstanding your question...to make a link you have to surround the img tag with a tags.

```
<a href="url.html">
    <img src="".../>
</a>
```

Comment: If you view the url you will see that the image is in a css div and floating on the side of the page. I guess I just wrap that css div as an a link?

Comment: Do you mean that you do not have an img tag?

Comment: it is being called via css. it is in a css div floating on the left side of the screen always in the middle of the screen

Answer (score 1):

The best way will be to use an anchor tag.

```
<a href="yourfilepath"><img src="imagepath" /></a>
```

[Anchor Tag - Images as Links](http://www.createafreewebsite.net/html_tutorial/anchor_tag_image.html)

Answer (score 1):

While wrapping your `<div>` in an `<a>` might work, I don't think you're allowed to put block-level elements inside an `<a>` (like you suggest on Vincent Ramdhanie's answer). Because of that, I would recommend this:

```
<div class="sidebox">
    <a href="http://example.com">
        &nbsp;
    </a>
</div>
```

Then, for your styles:

```
div.sidebox {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

div.sidebox a {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

The width and height for the `<div>` and the `<a>` should both be the same for this to work.

Comment: On second thought, the width and height properties for "div.sidebox a" might only need to be 100%, and not an absolute measurement. You may want to experiment with that.